# Mikrotik php_api через safe mode

Tags: php, api, mikrotik

Необходимо включение режима "Safe Mode" путем передачи запроса посредством php(api) на Mikrotik!

Или, какой командой включить "Safe mode" в терминале!

Нажатием <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> не подходит!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

возможно это поможет 
с помощью скриптов
https://ixnfo.com/bezopasnaya-udalennaya-rabota-s-mikrotik-kak-ne-poteryat-svyaz-s-ustroystvom.html

Для начала сохраним текущую рабочую конфигурацию:

system backup save name=backup.cfg
Создадим скрипт:

/system script add name=имя_скрипта policy=\
    ftp,reboot,read,write,policy,test,winbox,password,sniff,sensitive,api \
    source="delay 900 \
/n system backup load name=backup.cfg"
После создания его необходимо запустить командой:

system script run имя_скрипта
и через 900 секунд (это 15 минут) он восстановит настройки из сохраненного ранее файла настроек. Если выполняя настройки связь с устройством не прервалась до истечения 15 минут, скрипт можно остановить командой:

system script job remove имя_скрипта

Comment: День добрый. Постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы. Если ответ по ссылке слишком большой, то хотя бы основные моменты отразите в своём ответе ^__^

Comment: Да, такое решение я видел...И не один так говорит, думал, что может есть запрос полноценный через терминал или же через библиотеку api!